# Why is this sentence wrong? "Quelle idée est-ce qu'ils choisissent ?"

Tags: traduction, questions

I wanted to translate this sentence on Duolingo:

> "Which idea are they choosing?"

I used:

> "quelle idée est-ce qu'ils choisissent"

I believe I could use the following sentences instead:

> "Quelle(s) idée(s) choisissent-ils/elles."
>
> Ils/Elles choisissent "quelle(s) idée(s)."

But I don't understand why the sentence I used is not correct. I would appreciate if you could tell me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**(Thanks @jlliagre for the help)**

> Quelle idée choisissent-ils/elles ? (formal; inversion)
>
> Laquelle de ces idées choisissent-ils ? (another formal option)
>
> Ils/elles choisissent quelle idée ? (middle register)
>
> Quelle idée ils/elles choisissent ? (probably the most common middle register)
>
> C'est quelle idée qu'ils choisissent (another option) ?
>
> Quelle(s) idée(s) est-ce qu'ils/elles choisissent ?

*Quelle idée est-ce qu'ils choisissent ?* is not unheard but not very idiomatic and would be perceived as broken grammar because *quelle* is already introducing a question so *est-ce que* is redundant.